# How can I access this two objects here?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I access this two objects "public" and "secret" in the Wallet function here:

```
function Wallet(){
  var pair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
  return{
    public: pair.publicKey(),
    secret: pair.secret()
  }
}
```

Are they objects? I mean, is this function returning an array?

I'm trying this:

```
Wallet().public
Wallet().secret
```

But it returns me a different set of keys, they don't match cause I am calling twice the function, so I figured it out it corresponds a different key each time I call it.

How can I access these two "public" and "secret" strings but just calling at once the function?

Comment: Each time I call the function Wallet() it returns a different set of keys that match to each other. 

When I need to store them in a variable, for example: `var wallet = Wallet();`it stores a unique set of key pairs but I won't be able to access them unless I try this: var anotherWallet = new Wallet(); 

So I am looking for a solution where I can keep calling the function and keep returning me the different set of key pairs but matching. I think the only way is keep creating new variables?

Answer (score 1):

You first have to save the return value of `Wallet` to a variable and then access the public and private key:

```
let wallet = Wallet();
wallet.public;
wallet.private;
```

This way `Wallet`, and therefore `StellarSdk.Keypair.random();` is only executed once.

Comment: Thanks Luca it works! but when I need another key pair I would necessarily need to specified this: `let anotherKeypair = new Wallet()` ? or there is a way I can access different key pairs just calling the function at once?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to assign the function call to a variable. Is this a problem in a specific case?

Comment: Yes because I want a new key set when I call the function but In this case I would need to specify a new variable each time, so for example, users won't have new key set unless I've specified the `new Wallet()` before, then the amount of users with a new wallet is limited

Comment: Still don't see a problem here. You don't need to call it using the `new` keyword here, you are not initializing a Class. Can you share the code that is troubling here?

Comment: It isn't a problem per se but when I access the variable `let wallet = Wallet();`it stores a unique set of pairs and when I execute actually the function, it returns me a different key set every time I execute it and this is what I am looking for. A way I can keep executing the function and returning me a different set of keys, but also matching each other.

Comment: There are ways to make functions alsways return the same thing, yeah, singletons, or function factories, but both have their downsides, especially, that you still either need to make a variable for every keyset, or that you only have a single keyset per runtime, both don't seem to be any better than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Wallet(){
  var pair = StellarSdk.Keypair.random();
var obj={
    public: pair.publicKey(),
    secret: pair.secret()
}
return obj;
  }

var wallet = Wallet();
console.log(wallet.puplic);
console.log(wallet.secret);
```